# Get Constructor Matching Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, activator

I have a method which takes in a constructor arguments as

```
Expression<func<T>>
```

thus declared as

```
object[] _constructorArgs = () => new MyClass("StringParam", 56, "ThirdParam");
```

I would instantiate this object as;

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass), _constructorArgs);
```

Which works fine, but it's a bit slow.

Is there a way I can gather the types Constructor based on the contents of _constructorArgs so I would be able to call

```
ConstructorInfo.Invoke(_constructorArgs);
```

?

I know the Invoke is possible this way, it's just about finding the correct constructor based on the parameters in _constructorArgs.

**Edit - For clarity**

Apologies, I was very tired when I first asked this and should have given it more thought.

What I am doing is the following;

```
    public object Create<T>(Expression<Func<T>> constructor)
    {
        //I didn't include this step in the original code
        var constructorArguments =
            (((NewExpression)constructor.Body).Arguments.Select(
                argument => Expression.Lambda(argument).Compile().DynamicInvoke())).ToArray();

        object[] _args = constructorArguments;

        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), _args);
    }
```

However, if I do the following instead;

```
         ConstructorInfo c = type.GetConstructors().FirstOrDefault();

        //Get the types constructor
        return c.Invoke(_args);
```

I get better performance, I'm talking the first taking about 2800 milliseconds over a million iterations, using Invoke bringing that down to about 1000 milliseconds, thus 2.8 times faster.

This will work great if the first constructor always matches the arguments given, but this won't always be the case.

I want to know how I can get the correct ConstructorInfo based on arguments given.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Maybe you should provide a complete example? The second code block can't actually compile, you cannot assign a lambda (a `Func<MyClass>`) to a variable of type `object[]`.

Comment: Also, you should clarify the "slow" part. `Activator.CreateInstance` is not supposed to be that slow for normal usage and `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` is not going to be much faster. What kind of performance are you trying to achieve? Are you sure it's not your constructor code that is slow?

Comment: Jods, thanks for the reply. I had forgot to include the complication of the Lamda, I have now included it and further clarity in the original post. The times tested have been against the same constructor in both ways, so the constructor isn't the issue in this case. If there is a faster way than ConstructorInfo.Invoke(_args) then I will also be happy to look at that.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `DynamicInvoke` is very slow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a million new objects per second isn't fast enough for you, you're going to have to go deeper. You need to start caching things. The simplest thing to cache is the constructor itself, so that you don't have to search for the correct constructor all the time. However...

Why are you doing this? Why don't you simply call the lambda outright? You've got all the code to instantiate the class, and then you throw it away and use `Activator.CreateInstance`? Why? Even if you do that, you don't need to *search* for the constructor - `NewExpression.Constructor` has the `ConstructorInfo` you need. Just do

```
((NewExpression)constructor.Body).Constructor.Invoke(_args)
```

and you're done, no searching needed. All the metadata is already there in the expression tree.

Please explain why you can't simply do `return constructor();` (with caching if possible / needed - it's handy to pass things as lambda parameters, since you can then easily cache the method itself).

Comment: When caling constructor() I get the "Is a variable but is used like a method'. However changing this from Expression<func<T>> to Func<T> lets me do this, and has offered a significant performance increase. I'm exploring the options available to invoke members, which is why i'm so curious about performance. You've (Directly or indirectly) opened my eyes to a few options. Thanks!

Comment: @EverythingGeek Using a delegate directly (that's the `Func<T>` in this case) is one of the fastest options. The only thing that might be somewhat faster is using an interface; but it generally isn't worth it - the difference is rather small and working with delegates is *so* easy :) And yeah, you're right, if you use `Expression<Func<T>>`, you first have to do the `Compile`, which is counter-productive in your case - changing the expression tree to a simple delegate lets the compiler prepare everything at compile-time, rather than run-time (well, there's the JIT compilation, but :))

Answer (score 1):

`Activator.CreateInstance()` under the hood calls `GetConstructors()` and iterates over them to find the matching ones. This would explain the difference in performance - and if you roll your own implementation chances are you will end up with the same or worse performance.

You could simplify the process by comparing types using `parameterType.IsAssignableFrom(argType)`, and return the first match - you may end up using a different constructor than `Activator.CreateInstance()` though because it uses the *best match*, not the *first match*:

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass { }

class Test
{
    public Test(BaseClass c)
    {
    }

    public Test(DerivedClass c)
    {
    }
}

// Uses the most specific constructor, Test(DerivedClass):
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test), new DerivedClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but I found a nice implementation with caching, which claims to be 70 times faster thant Activator.CreateInstance;

```
this.Item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new Object[] { x, y }, null); // Classical approach
this.Item = Constructor<Func<int,int,T>>.Ctor(x,y); // Dynamic constructor approach
```

The complete implementation can be found here:
http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/32756/blog2078.html